# How do I join two table with group by order by

Tags: mysql

I'm getting headache to join my table. Currently I used this way

```
<?php
$result  = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS rows, ad_userid
FROM ads
GROUP BY ad_userid
ORDER BY rows DESC
LIMIT 5
");
while ($top = $db->fetch($result)) {
    $selectuser = $db->query("SELECT * 
                      FROM users 
                      WHERE user_id='".intval($top['ad_userid'])."'
                      ");
    $user = $db->fetch($selectuser);
?>
<li><a href="<?php echo $url;?>/user/<?php echo $user['user_id']; ?>/"><?php echo $user['user_name'].' '.$top['rows']; ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

The result is fine but let me know a simple way to join this table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with subquery:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS rows, ad_userid
    FROM ads
    GROUP BY ad_userid
    ORDER BY rows DESC
    LIMIT 5 
) AS t1 LEFT JOIN users AS t2 ON t2.user_id = t1.ad_userid
```

**UPDATE (@Marc B)**
From the MySQL doc.

> There are some errors that apply only
>   to subqueries. This section describes
>   them.  ... Unsupported subquery
>   syntax:
>
> ERROR 1235 (ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_YET)
>   SQLSTATE = 42000 Message = "This
>   version of MySQL does not yet support
>   'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'"
>   This means that statements of the
>   following form do not work yet:
>
> SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE s1 IN (SELECT
>   s2 FROM t2 ORDER BY s1 LIMIT 1)

That correct Mark, LIMIT in subquery is not supported but only when used in IN/ALL/ANY/SOME...  You can freely use it in a FROM clause.

I've just write this kind of query few hours ago and it seems to work fine.

Comment: MySQL doesn't support LIMITS in subqueries.